# How to create semi transparent panel

Tags: c#, panel

I have a panel on a form

How do i make it semitransparent,

Comment: In which GUI framework ?

Comment: From your question i understand that you want your Form background to be visible through the semitransparent panel? You aren't trying to make the form transparent with the panel docked exactly over the form right?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create your own custom panel to achieve this.

There is a nice article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx) that explains how this can be done.